# Distance Formula not working while comparing 2 variables on Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, geolocation

I have created a button on the Accounts page which launches a Screen flow to potentially show nearby accounts to the one the user is currently viewing. Below is the screen flow:
[image]

I am having a problem with the formula to compare the geolcations of the other accounts against the current account the user is viewing.

I am getting the following error in the collection filter:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. I got the code from the following link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_distance.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

The RecordId variable is a String, rather than the Account record itself. To use any fields on that you'll need to first retrieve the Account using the RecordId as a filter, and then use the retrieved Account record in your formula.

Along with that, you're likely to need to provide some sort of filter on the Get All Accounts node if you haven't already. This is limited to 50,000 records so if you end up exceeding this your Flow will throw an error to the user.